# Build solana-client for wasm target

Tags: solana-client

Has anyone been able to build solana-client for a wasm32-unknown-unknown target (wasm-pack build --target web)?

Getting the following error building `gethostname` dependency

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `gethostname_impl` in this scope
  --> /Users/josep/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gethostname-0.2.3/src/lib.rs:58:5
   |
58 |     gethostname_impl()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `gethostname` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Comment: Did you get this working? Any links to source examples? Has anyone tried that Solana-wasm-client crate?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [solana-client-wasm crate](https://crates.io/crates/solana-client-wasm). [Source](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/tree/master/wasm/solana-client).

Answer (score 0):

Solana Playground has an implementation of `solana-client` in WASM. I think it's a pretty comprehensive re-implementation though. You can see the full source code here: https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/tree/master/wasm/solana-client